# Null fields after form submit in Spring

Tags: forms, spring, data-binding, orm, model

I've got a Product with a Rating rating attribute. I've got a product update form (updateStart method) which doesn't contain the rating field (since I don't want it to be editable).

The problem is that when I submit the form (with update method), the rating is automatically set to null.
So I tried to add the Rating to the form model in updateStart, retrieving it in the update method, but it keeps being rewritten as well.

I tried to set a @SessionAttributes("rating") annotation in the controller. This time the rating value is kept, but Spring creates a new entry in the database, cloned from the other rating object, and attaches it to the Product.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("rating")
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductsController {

@RequestMapping("/update_start")
public String updateStart(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Model model) throws BusinessException {
    Product product = productService.findProductById(id);

System.out.println("RATING A START "+product.getRating().getAbsoluteRating());

    List<Category> categories = productService.findAllCategories();
    model.addAttribute("categories", categories);
    model.addAttribute("product", product);
    model.addAttribute("id", id);
    model.addAttribute("rating",product.getRating());
    return "products.updateform";   
}

@RequestMapping(value="/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(@ModelAttribute("rating") Rating rating, @ModelAttribute Product product, BindingResult bindingResult) throws BusinessException {

    System.out.println("RATING A UPDATE "+rating.getAbsoluteRating());

    validator.validate(product, bindingResult);

    List<Image> images = imageService.getProductImages(product.getId());

    product.setRating(rating);

    productService.updateProduct(product,images,sellerid);
    return "redirect:/products/viewsforsellers.do";
}   
}
```

What can I do?

**EDIT:** I'd prefer to avoid placing a hidden input field with ratingId in my form.

Comment: When you say that you add the rating to the form, do you add all fields or just the id?  Is rating an entity?

Comment: @KevinBowersox Yes, Rating is an entity. I tried to add it to the model (not to the form inputs) using this: model.addAttribute("rating",product.getRating());

Comment: The rating in your form is a drop down?

Comment: @kiduxa As I said, the product update form (updateStart method) doesn't contain the rating field (since I don't want it to be editable).

Answer (score 0):

In the form include a hidden input with the `name` and `value` specified for the `Rating`.  The value should include

```
<form>
    <input name="product.rating" value="${product.rating.id}"/>
    <!-- Other fields -->
</form>
```

Now when the request comes over the wire it should include a `Rating` specified by `id` for the product.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(@ModelAttribute Product product, BindingResult bindingResult) throws BusinessException {
     //implementation
}
```

`@ModelAttribute` should attempt to bind this parameter to the `Product` however it is not aware of what a `Rating` is.  This is where a `Converter` comes into play.  A `Converter` is used during databinding to tell Spring MVC how to map a field of type `String` to a field of type `Rating`.

```
public class StringToRatingConverter implements Converter<String, Rating> {


    public Rating convert(String source) {
           //Use the source String to convert to rating
           //Possibly via database call or enum conversion, pending ratings type and definition
           //Ultimately the code needs to return the appropriate object of type Rating

           return rating;  //The above implementation will create the rating object.
        }
    }
```

The `StringToRatingConverter` must then be registered in the `dispatcher` configuration file.

```
    <!-- Register Converters - Used for data binding-->
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean class="fully.qualified.path.to.StringToRatingConverter"/>
        </list> 
    </property>
</bean>
```

The first time I encountered this scenario, I captured it in a [post on my blog](http://blog-tothought.rhcloud.com/post/18), which you may be helpful.

Comment: I'd like to avoid putting an hidden field in my form, since it could be easily modified using firebug. Moreover, if I put the rating id field in the form, I could use its value to directly retrieve (with a database query) the related Rating object without using a converter. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I agree @KurtBourbaki, did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You should add "types" element to your `@SessionAttributes("rating")` annotation in order properties of attributes to be kept; e.g.

```
@SessionAttributes(types = Rating.class, names = "rating")
```